# Azure CDN configration the endpoint with different storage accounts

Tags: azure, storage, azure-blob-storage, cdn

everyone. I have two storage accounts. One of them for the USA, another for Australia. Both of them have a folder with the number 77. This folder has blobs only for Australia's users. In future, the folder 77 will be deleted from the USA.
Question: I want to configure the Azure CDN storage endpoint with a custom domain (Origin is the USA's storage account). In case the URL has something like `mycustomdomain/files/77/{fileID}` in the rules engine should have a rule, where URL should rewrite from USA's storage account to Australia. I created the rule, but something goes wrong.

[Example, what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEZvL.png)

> `OutOfRangeInput` One of the request
> inputs is out of range. RequestId:786ab21e-e01e-0064-5255-f95da2000000
> Time:2021-02-02T11:24:07.2067671Z

How I can do it?

Comment: Do you mean that you wanna to change the endpoint which is created to connect to the USA storage to connect Aus storage? If so, I think you need to create a new endpoint.

Comment: I have the endpoint. It has named mydomain-files and it returns a link 'mydomain-files/files/77/{fileid}. and I want to create a mechanism that under this custom domain will rewrite the URL to correct storage account if the user takes files from 77 folder

Comment: I haven't found any solution to achieve your goal by creating such a mechanism.